# Classification of discontinuities

Tags: calculus

I was reading something which I do not understand.

I saw a conclusion that says that for any function that has a removable discontinuity or jump discontinuity (step discontinuity) then the function has no Indefinite integral.

So I took a look at [$ \frac {1}{n} $](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/n)

So as I saw the function suffer from jump discontinuity in $x = 0$.

But still as you can see it has Indefinite integral which is $\log(n)$.

So was something wrong in the statement I read or I misinterpreted the $\frac {1}{n}$ or the statement

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: The discontinuity at $x=0$ is not a jump discontinuity. A jump discontinuity must have both its left hand limit and its right hand limit be finite.

Comment: $\log x$ is not an antiderivative of $1/x$ on any neighbourhood of  $x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the theorem that derivatives cannot have jump discontinuities. This is a consequence of the Mean Value Theorem and has been discussed elsewhere on math.stackexchange.com

About your example the function $1/x$ does not have a jump discontinuity, but rather an infinity at $ x = 0$ so it does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Just because there is a jump discontinuity does not mean the function does not have an indefinite integral. Just take the integral of the respective functions with exclusion of the value that it's jumped at.

Comment: The concept of an indefinite integral (anti-derivative) of $f(x)$ implicitly assumes that there is some interval in which we have a function $g(x)$ such that $g'(x) = f(x)$ on that interval. So strictly speaking when we talk about indefinite integral we should also take note of the interval in which it is valid.